# Pandas/SQL only return results where groupby has at least n rows

Tags: python, sql, pandas, postgresql

I have a stock database of the following form where data is given by the **minute.**

[image]

I want to fetch all results which have at least **N** rows for a particular ticker, for a particular date. (when grouped by **ticker and date**)

The purpose is to ignore missing data for a given ticker on a given date. There should be at least 629 rows for any given ticker,date combination. Anything less than this, I want to ignore that combination.

I tried something like the following but it wasn't working

```
start_date = '2021-11-08'
SQL = "SELECT datetime, datetime_utc, ticker,open,close,session_type, high,low,volume FROM candles WHERE id in (SELECT id from candles WHERE session_type='Live' GROUP BY datetime, ticker HAVING COUNT(ID) >= 629) AND datetime >= '{} 00:00:00'::timestamp ORDER BY ticker, datetime_utc ASC".format(start_date)
```

Could anyone point me at the right SQL incantation? I am using postgres > 9.6.

**sample data** (apologies i tried to set up an SQL fiddle but it wasn't allowing me to due to character limitations, then data type limitations. The data is below in json, set to be read by pandas)

```
df = pd.io.json.read_json('{"datetime":{"12372":1636572720000,"12351":1636571460000,"12493":1636590240000,"15210":1636633380000,"16212":1636642500000,"16009":1636560060000,"12213":1636554180000,"16386":1636657800000,"13580":1636572660000,"14733":1636659000000,"12086":1636537200000,"14802":1636667880000,"14407":1636585980000,"14356":1636577640000,"16086":1636574280000,"15437":1636661040000,"14115":1636577400000,"14331":1636576140000,"12457":1636582800000,"14871":1636678080000},"datetime_utc":{"12372":1636572720000,"12351":1636571460000,"12493":1636590240000,"15210":1636633380000,"16212":1636642500000,"16009":1636560060000,"12213":1636554180000,"16386":1636657800000,"13580":1636572660000,"14733":1636659000000,"12086":1636537200000,"14802":1636667880000,"14407":1636585980000,"14356":1636577640000,"16086":1636574280000,"15437":1636661040000,"14115":1636577400000,"14331":1636576140000,"12457":1636582800000,"14871":1636678080000},"ticker":{"12372":"AAPL","12351":"AAPL","12493":"AAPL","15210":"AAPL","16212":"NET","16009":"NET","12213":"AAPL","16386":"NET","13580":"NET","14733":"AAPL","12086":"AAPL","14802":"AAPL","14407":"AAPL","14356":"AAPL","16086":"NET","15437":"AAPL","14115":"NET","14331":"AAPL","12457":"AAPL","14871":"AAPL"},"open":{"12372":148.29,"12351":148.44,"12493":148.1,"15210":148.68,"16212":199.72,"16009":202.27,"12213":150.21,"16386":198.65,"13580":194.9,"14733":147.94,"12086":150.2,"14802":147.87,"14407":148.1,"14356":148.09,"16086":193.82,"15437":148.01,"14115":194.64,"14331":148.07,"12457":148.12,"14871":148.2},"close":{"12372":148.32,"12351":148.44,"12493":148.15,"15210":148.69,"16212":199.32,"16009":202.52,"12213":150.25,"16386":198.57,"13580":194.96,"14733":147.99,"12086":150.17,"14802":147.9,"14407":148.1,"14356":147.99,"16086":194.43,"15437":148.01,"14115":194.78,"14331":148.05,"12457":148.11,"14871":148.28},"session_type":{"12372":"Live","12351":"Live","12493":"Post","15210":"Pre","16212":"Live","16009":"Live","12213":"Pre","16386":"Live","13580":"Live","14733":"Live","12086":"Pre","14802":"Post","14407":"Post","14356":"Live","16086":"Live","15437":"Live","14115":"Live","14331":"Live","12457":"Post","14871":"Post"},"high":{"12372":148.3600006104,"12351":148.4700012207,"12493":148.15,"15210":148.69,"16212":199.8399963379,"16009":202.5249938965,"12213":150.25,"16386":198.6499938965,"13580":195.0299987793,"14733":147.9900054932,"12086":150.2,"14802":147.9,"14407":148.1,"14356":148.1049957275,"16086":194.4400024414,"15437":148.0399932861,"14115":195.1699981689,"14331":148.0800018311,"12457":148.12,"14871":148.28},"low":{"12372":148.26,"12351":148.38,"12493":148.06,"15210":148.68,"16212":199.15,"16009":202.27,"12213":150.2,"16386":198.49,"13580":194.79,"14733":147.93,"12086":150.16,"14802":147.85,"14407":148.1,"14356":147.98,"16086":193.82,"15437":148.0,"14115":194.64,"14331":148.01,"12457":148.07,"14871":148.2},"volume":{"12372":99551.0,"12351":68985.0,"12493":0.0,"15210":0.0,"16212":9016.0,"16009":2974.0,"12213":0.0,"16386":1395.0,"13580":5943.0,"14733":59854.0,"12086":0.0,"14802":0.0,"14407":0.0,"14356":341196.0,"16086":8715.0,"15437":45495.0,"14115":16535.0,"14331":173785.0,"12457":0.0,"14871":0.0},"date":{"12372":1636502400000,"12351":1636502400000,"12493":1636502400000,"15210":1636588800000,"16212":1636588800000,"16009":1636502400000,"12213":1636502400000,"16386":1636588800000,"13580":1636502400000,"14733":1636588800000,"12086":1636502400000,"14802":1636588800000,"14407":1636502400000,"14356":1636502400000,"16086":1636502400000,"15437":1636588800000,"14115":1636502400000,"14331":1636502400000,"12457":1636502400000,"14871":1636588800000}}')
```

**Expected result**

if N = 4, then the results will exclude NET on 2021-11-11. (count of all shown here for illustration)
[image]

Like below (sample only)
[image]

Comment: @SalmanA whoops sorry about that - database should have ID and autoincremented - fixed

Comment: Do you have a date column, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use analytical function (window function) to count rows for each date and ticker combination.

```
select datetime, datetime_utc, ticker,open,close,session_type, high,low,volume 
from (
    SELECT datetime, datetime_utc, ticker,open,close,session_type, high,low,volume,
           COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY CAST(datetime AS DATE), ticker) as C
    FROM candles 
)
WHERE C >= 5
```

I am not familiar with postgres, so it may contain syntax problem.

Comment: Exactly what i needed! Tweaking it for postgres, the working query was `SELECT  datetime, datetime_utc, ticker,open,close,session_type, high,low,volume FROM
 (SELECT datetime, datetime_utc, ticker,open,close,session_type, high,low,volume, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY CAST(datetime AS DATE), ticker) as C
    FROM candles) as temp WHERE temp.C > 629 ORDER BY ticker, datetime ASC`. Thank you!

Comment: actually whoops it didnt seem to work with my actual database...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`pandasql`](https://pypi.org/project/pandasql/) with a nested [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to count the daily data points for all tickers and use an inner join

```
import pandasql as ps

N=4
df_select = ps.sqldf(f"select df.* from (select count(*) as count, ticker, date from df group by date, ticker having count >= {N}) df_counts left join df on df.ticker=df_counts.ticker and df.date=df_counts.date")
```

Output:
[image]